# JSON keep Getting the old data

Tags: android, json

My JSON parser keep getting my member data which I accessed earlier even when I was supposed to get another data EX:Job data. Here is my JSONParser.java Code:

```
package travenz.tacos;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
       try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        url += "?";
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
        Log.d("JSON", json);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       // try parse the string to a JSON object
       try {
           jObj = new JSONObject(json);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
       }

       // return JSON String
       return jObj;

}
public JSONObject setJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();         

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 20);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.d("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrlWithParams(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?"+paramString;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        Log.d("url", url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 20);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.d("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;    

    }
}
```

and this is my code to get job data:

```
private static final String JOB_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/DatabaseCon/selectalltugas.php";
class LoadJobList extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(JobSchedule.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Jobs ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Job JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(JOB_URL);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Job JSON: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                job = json.getJSONArray(TAG_JOBS);
                // looping through All messages
                for (int i = 0; i < job.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = job.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                    String place = c.getString(TAG_PLACE);
                    String detail = c.getString(TAG_DETAIL);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                    map.put(TAG_TIME, time);
                    map.put(TAG_PLACE, place);
                    map.put(TAG_DETAIL, detail);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    JobList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                nodata = true;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
       protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            JobSchedule.this, JobList,
                            R.layout.job_list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_NAME, TAG_DATE, TAG_TIME, TAG_PLACE },
                            new int[] {R.id.jid, R.id.name, R.id.date, R.id.time, R.id.place });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.job_schedule, menu);
        return true;
        }

}
```

from the URL I posted above, It should be the correct php and I already checked the php file to. It definitely typed: select * from jobs instead of members but I'm still getting my previously accessed member data even if I restarted my emulator and didn't enter the member page first

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but why are you using `runOnUiThread` in your `onPostExecute` method? `onPostExecute` runs on the main/UI thread anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `jObj` as a class level variable, you should probably have it as a method level variable (declare it inside the `getJsonFromUrl()` method) and assign it a default value or `null`.

I would guess that you are catching a JSONException or one of the other connection Exceptions and the previous value for it is not getting set to the new input and then you are returning the old version or worse, a version from another method's last run.

In this case, even though errors occur either fetching or parsing the JSON you return the `jObj` regardless. This means that if an error has occurred then `jObj` will still be set to its last value and that gets returned instead.

The same also holds true for the other class level variables (InputStream is and String json). I would actually suggest that you remove all class level variables and make all the class' methods `static`. That way you can be sure no stale data is ever returned.

Here is your class changed:

```
public class JSONParser
{
    public static JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url)
    {
        String json = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;

        // Making HTTP request
        try
        {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            url += "?";
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            json = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
            Log.d("JSON", json);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try
        {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "json String was null");
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }

    public static JSONObject setJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        String json = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;
        // Making HTTP request
        try
        {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 20);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("JSON", json);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        finally 
        {
            // you should always close any open handles in a finally clause
            if (is != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {}
            }
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try
        {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "json String was null");
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }

    public static JSONObject getJSONFromUrlWithParams(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        String json = null;
        JSONObject jObj = null;

        // Making HTTP request
        try
        {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.d("url", url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 20);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("JSON", json);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (is != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    is.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try
        {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Note that this is just a possible implementation that developed slowly as the OP supplied more code. The answer by JayR is an probably the better fix. The choice to make the JSONParser have static methods is an optional design decision. However, the changes made to closing the InputStream safely probably should still be applied.

Comment: oh, I declared my jObj as a public variable. Should I change it to be declared at each method instead? Btw, I have added my whole JSONParser.java lf that would help more

Comment: I've edited in an edited version of your class. All I did was change the scope of the variables and make the methods static so you don't have to instantiate the class to use them. You can just call `JSONObject someJsonObj = JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);` from wherever you want to use the methods. (I also changed where you close your InputStreams to ensure that they always get closed).

Comment: thanks, but it appears that the method cannot be set as static but I just remove the static word and poof! it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is because you only use a single instance of JSONParser when you are calling a web service call.

Try to create a new instance for every call so that they have different response.

you can do such.

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(JOB_URL);
```

'json' has now the value of response you want.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: I get your point, your suggestion is just another way of solving my problem just like the comment above so thanks

Comment: Yes, and he mention my answer as better fix. Thanks anyway then.